# What is the right verb to use in “I have just ( ) 15?

Tags: verbs

I was baffled when I happened to pick up an English drill book of my granddaughter who is high schooler, and found a question asking to fill the sentence, “I have just (   ) 15.”

I’ve never thought of seriously what is the right word to use to express reaching a certain age.
Though it must be a self-evident question, I, as a non-native English speaker am not confident of what is the right answer to this question, when asked in face.

Is it ‘gotten’, ‘been’, ‘reached’, ‘grown to’, ‘come off, become’ or what else?
What is the right verb?

Comment: I work in a Japanese Junior High School. I can assure you this is not the only astonishing thing you'll find in the text books.

Comment: @Pitarou. I presume you're teaching in a school in Narita, aren't you? I'm living in Kashiwa near to you. Well, what do you tell your students, is the right answer?

Comment: The present perfect doesn't get a lot of attention at junior high level. But I think Jonathan Spirit's answer is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turned or become are the most common words I've heard other native British English speakers say. I'm one also, and I use those commonly. I don't know about American English (or Canadian or Australian).

Comment: *Turned* is most common in American English as well.

Comment: I would never even use ‘become’. ‘Turn’ is basically the only verb I'd use naturally.